# Hypothesis Testing Using Summations

Tags: probability, statistics

Assuming that n=12 and $\sum_{i=1}^n  Y_i^{2}\tag{} = 42 $ perform a level $\alpha=0.05  $ hypothesis test of the following hypothesis. 
$$H_o=\theta=\theta_o=2$$ against the alternative $$H_a: \theta >2$$. Explain the rejection region.
I know that $Y_i^{2}$ is a chi-squared with 2 degrees of freedom or an exponential with expectation 2. And it is a small sample so it would be a t-test. But am unsure on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say something about your model (what is $\theta$). Anyway,

**Hint:** there are [good reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) to take the likelihood-ratio test.